# Transforming an estimator to overestimate

Tags: data-transformation, loss-functions, estimators

I have an estimator $\mu^*$ of a the mean $\mu$ of a certain distribution that I obtained using a variational technique (basically just establishing a bound on $\mu$ and finding a trial function that minimizes that bound). My estimator $\mu^*$ has therefore the property that:

$\mu \leq \mu^*$

I want to compare the performance of my estimator to estimators obtained by other means (e.g. through MCMC) if possible by using the same variational bound. To do this, I want a transformation that converts any estimator into an overestimator. Specifically, I want some sort of transformation $f$ such that for any estimator $\mu'$ of $\mu$, we have that $\mu \leq f(\mu')$ and that for a loss function $L$ with respect to $\mu$ (e.g. least squares) $f$ has the property that $E[L(\mu', \mu)] = E[L(f(\mu'), \mu)]$.
My question is, does this transformation $f$ even exist or if not is there an approximation such that $E[L(f(\mu'), \mu)]$ lies relatively close to $E[L(\mu', \mu)]$?

Rao-Blackwellization may help here, but finding a sufficient statistic may be hard in my case and I don't know a priori if the estimator $\mu'$ is unbiased.